# Print to terminal in a multithreaded environment for CRAN R package

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

I am updating a CRAN package that needs C++ compilation. CRAN forbids `std::cout <<` but allows `Rcpp::Rcout <<`. The latter however crashes the program in a multithreaded environment. I am using `RcppParallel` for multithreading. Is there an alternative without importing new R packages besides `Rcpp` and `RcppParallel` ?

Thank you!

A solution: put `Rcpp::Rcout << ...` in a `tbb::spin_mutex` locking scope.

Comment: Rock, meet hard place.  You _cannot_ use `std::cout` as CRAN Policy does not want you to mix two output streams.   And _within a parallel section you cannot use `Rcpp::Rcout`_ as you cannot call back to R from such a section.   So rethink your approach and need for printing.  This is not going to be solved by another package.

Comment: What he said before I said it....

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the comment Dirk. I kept messing with this and found putting `Rcout << ...` in a mutex scope works out fine.